# Prevent External Login redirect writing cookies using ASP.NET Identity 2

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

Apart from finding the newish ASP.NET Identity 2 system bulky and confusing. I'm just trying to do something simple, provide the oAuth credentials, and login with facebook.

After getting this working, the response writes a massive 'state' string and sets an equally large cookie.  Now this is an anonymous user, so what's in this value?

It's not helpful that the libs MS provide for this are all closed sourced, and no documentation exists.  Decompiling the few dozen libs required for Identity to work has yielded no insight.

**What are the cookies, where are they set, and how can they be turned off?**

Comment: What is the name of the cookie?

Comment: @JustinHelgerson The cookie is called '.AspNet.Correlation.Facebook' - I'm playing around with 'app.UseExternalSignInCookie()' in the OWIN Startup file without success. I'm just not sure why a cookie is even needed.